# New line in Assembly (LC-3)

Tags: assembly, lc3

I am having a problem getting the next line to print after getting user input.
the output should be:

```
5
54321END
```

; Description:
; This program displays a prompt to the user, `"Enter count [1-9]: "`, to request
; the number of times to loop and output to the screen. The number of times to
; loop will be limited to between 1 and 9.

```
.ORIG x3000         ; Start at memory location x3000
    LEA R0, QUESTION    ; Load Question into R0
    PUTS            ; print prompt to console
    GETC
    LEA R5, NEWLINE
    OUT         ; Take a character input from keyboard, then store in R0
    LD R1, NEGASCII     ; Load NegASCII into R1
    ADD R2, R0, R1      ; Strip ASCII, store integer into R2
    LD R3, ASCII        ; Load Ascii into R3

LOOP            ; initialize loop to write counter to console
    ADD R0, R2, R3      ; make sure value is printabele to console
    OUT             ; Print to console
    ADD R2, R2, #-1     ; subtract the loop counter by 1
    BRnp LOOP       ; Call the loop again
    LEA R0, FINAL
    PUTS
    CLRIO
    HALT

NEWLINE .FILL x0A
QUESTION .STRINGZ "Enter count[1-9]: "  ; Create Question Prompt
NEGASCII .FILL xFFD0            ; give NEGASCII value of -x0030
ASCII .FILL x0030           ; Set ASCII value to 0
FINAL .STRINGZ "END\n"          ; Create Final Prompt

.END
```

The output for the code above is
`554321END` with an empty line after it.

Comment: `OUT` does not take a pointer and doesn't use `R5` (but you know both of these since you use it properly later). Try `LD R0, NEWLINE` instead.